# Error in MEEM(object, conLin, control$niterEM) / fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, nlme

I'm trying to make a multilevel mediation analysis (as done [here](https://quantdev.ssri.psu.edu/sites/qdev/files/APA-ATI_ILD_Session_O_-_Within-person_Mediation.html) and [here](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-perform-mediation-with-multilevel-data-method-2/)).

```
library(data.table)
library(lme4)
library(nlme)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)

# Simulated data ------------------------------------------------------------------
dt_1 <- data.table(id = rep(1:10, each=4),
                   time = as.factor(rep(1:4, 10)),
                   x = rnorm(40),
                   m = rnorm(40),
                   y = rnorm(40))

# Melt m and y into z ------------------------------------------------------------------
dt_2 <- dt_1 %>%
  mutate(mm = m, .after=x) %>%
  melt(id.vars = c("id","time","x","mm"),
       na.rm = F,
       variable.name = "dv",
       value.name = "z") %>%
  within({
    dy <- as.integer(dv == "y")
    dm <- as.integer(dv == "m")
    }) %>%
  arrange(id,time)

> head(dt_2,4)
   id time          x         mm dv          z dm dy
1:  1    1 -0.6264538 -0.1645236  m -0.1645236  1  0
2:  1    1 -0.6264538 -0.1645236  y -0.5686687  0  1
3:  1    2  0.1836433 -0.2533617  m -0.2533617  1  0
4:  1    2  0.1836433 -0.2533617  y -0.1351786  0  1

# lme mediation model ------------------------------------------------------------------
model_lme <- lme(fixed = z ~ 0 + 
                             dm + dm:x + dm:time + #m as outcome
                             dy + dy:mm + dy:x + dy:time, #y as outcome
                 random = ~ 0  +  dm:x + dy:mm + dy:x | id, 
                 weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | dm), #separate sigma^{2}_{e} for each outcome
                 data = dt_2,
                 na.action = na.exclude)

Error in MEEM(object, conLin, control$niterEM): Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1

# lmer mediation model ------------------------------------------------------------------
model_lmer <- lmer(z ~ 0 + dm + dm:x + dm:time + dy + dy:mm + dy:x + dy:time +
                     (0  +  dm:x + dy:mm + dy:x | id) + (0 + dm | time), 
                  data = dt_2,
                  na.action = na.exclude)

fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient
```

I've seen some posts about these error (nlme) / warning (lme4) (eg, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68028979/error-in-meemobject-conlin-controlniterem-singularity-in-backsolve-at-lev) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50505290/singularity-in-backsolve-at-level-0-block-1-in-lme-model)), but I didn't figure out what is the problem here.

I checked

```
X <- model.matrix(~0 + dm + dm:x + dm:time + dy + dy:mm + dy:x + dy:time, data=dt_2)

> caret::findLinearCombos(X)
$linearCombos
$linearCombos[[1]]
[1] 7 1 4 5 6

$remove
[1] 7
```

but I don't quite understand the output.

From the summary of `model_lmer` I verify that `dm:time4` and `time1:dy` coefficients are missing, but why? There are all the possible combinations (0/0, 0/1, 1/0, 1/1) in the dataset.

```
Fixed effects:
         Estimate Std. Error t value
dm        0.30898    0.92355   0.335
dy        0.03397    0.27480   0.124
dm:x      0.21267    0.19138   1.111
dm:time1 -0.19713    1.30583  -0.151
dm:time2 -0.30206    1.30544  -0.231
dm:time3 -0.20828    1.30620  -0.159
dy:mm     0.22625    0.18728   1.208
x:dy     -0.37747    0.17130  -2.204
time2:dy  0.29894    0.39123   0.764
time3:dy  0.22640    0.39609   0.572
time4:dy -0.16758    0.39457  -0.425
```

On the other hand, using `time` as numeric gives no error/warning:

```
# lmer mediation model - time as numeric
model_lmer2 <- lmer(z ~ 0 + dm + dm:x + dm:time + dy + dy:mm + dy:x + dy:time +
                     (0  +  dm:x + dy:mm + dy:x | id) + (0 + dm | time), 
                  data = within(dt_2, time <- as.numeric(time)),
                  na.action = na.exclude)
```

It's true that one can know `dm` from `dy` (if one is 1 the other is 0), but if that was the problem, this last model (`model_lmer2`) would still give a warning, I guess.

In my real dataset, I could eventually use `time` as numeric (although not my first approach), but I would like to understand what the problem is with using it as categorical.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is really a generic question about linear model construction/formulas in R: it's not mixed-model specific.

Let's look at the *names* of the columns involved in the multicollinear combination of variables (i.e. columns 7, 1, 4, 5, 6):

```r
cc <- caret::findLinearCombos(X)
colnames(X)[cc$linearCombos[[1]]]
## [1] "dm:time4" "dm"       "dm:time1" "dm:time2" "dm:time3"
```

This is telling us that the main effect of `dm` is confounded with the `dm:time` interaction; once we know `dm:time[i]` for all levels of `i`, the main effect of `dm` is redundant.

It's too bad that `lme` doesn't automatically drop columns to adjust for multicollinearity as `lmer` does, and that `lmer` doesn't have a super-convenient way to model heteroscedasticity à la `varIdent()`; it is possible [but it's a nuisance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67198942/heterocesdastic-model-of-mixed-effects-via-lmer-function).  It would be *possible* to build the auto-dropping into `nlme`, or `glmmTMB` (which can also model heteroscedasticity easily), but no-one's gotten around to it yet).

... if you're OK with specifying `dm:time` and leaving `dm` out of your model then that might be easiest!

---

You can experiment with what happens with different model specifications:

```r
lc <- function(f) {
    X <- model.matrix(f, dt_2)
    cc <- caret::findLinearCombos(X)
    lapply(cc$linearCombos, function(z) colnames(X)[z])
}

lc(~0 + dm + dm:time)
lc(~0 + dy + dy:time)
lc(~0 + dm + dm:time + dy + dy:time)
lc(~0 + dy + dy:time + dm + dm:time)
```

or similar stuff looking at the (heads of) the model matrices, column names of the model matrices, etc..

Comment: I'm probably missing something very easy, but in that case 1) doesn't `caret::findLinearCombos(X)` should also identify `dy` and `dy:time` as collinear? and 2) how are these interactions different from all other categorical-categorical interactions in any model? It's because I have `dy` and `dm=1-dy` and their interactions with `time` in the model? Thank you, @BenBolker!

Comment: I'm not sure, I'd have to spend more time looking at model matrices and thinking about it. As you can see from the examples I gave above, `dy` and `dy:time` *are* collinear if they're in a model alone.  For reasons I don't understand, `head(model.matrix(~0 + dy + dy:time + dm + dm:time, dt_2))` flips the order of the names for `dm:time` (`timex:dm`) *and* automatically drops the `time1:dm` column ... ?

Comment: Thanks for your help @BenBolker. After some tries, I got the model to work by creating one binary variable (0/1) for each level of time and also remove `dm` and `dy` as you suggested. Even for inclusing of binary factors (other covariates), I had to recode them to numeric 0/1